# How do I connect a regular hard drive to a laptop to clone data on it?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, clone

I want to clone a laptop partition to the hard disk of a computer (not an external hard disk), but how can I do that?

In the past I used EaseUS software to clone the disk to an external hard drive, but now the problem is: How do I connect the computer's hard disk to the laptop to create the clone?

Comment: 3.5inch or 2.5 inch ? pata or sata?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it is sata

Comment: just to make it clearer: you have a laptop, you dont want to open it, you dont want any cables to the laptop-internal disk. then you want to transfer the bytes of that disk to another machine's disk which you don't like to open as well?

Comment: you can use that approach (for me is same i don't want to open laptop if it is not necessarily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options really. *Thankfully* sata is standardised (unlike pata), so you could probably get a [SATA->USB adaptor](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=sata%20usb%20adaptor&oq=sata%20usb%20adaptor&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l4j62.2618&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of some sort. If your laptop has e-sata, you could get an esata adaptor - which will be faster. Not all laptops do though.

Another option might be to network the laptop and desktop (gig-e or 100 mbps. Don't even THINK about doing an image over wifi) and saving the image to a network drive.

Comment: thnx for answare, let's say that i want to use second soulution, i want to know is it possible to save image on network drive of pc disk if it don't have os?

Comment: On the laptop? You'd probably be able to use clonezilla. If the PC dosen't have an OS, probably boot freenas on it.

Comment: @tonni: you need an OS at least when creating the image. if that OS is  capable of storing the bytes you read from the disk to xyz is up the OS you are using. (usb-linux etc comes to mind)

Comment: ok i will try that (i don't have os on pc, on laptop i have), will try clone over the network with clonezilla and freenas, one more time thnx for answares

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiveCD from Clonezilla.org. It allows you to clone your disk via network. It has a simple wizard that guide you through cloning process.